# ZPL print Italic Bold and Underline

Tags: zpl

I need to print ZPL with dynamic content.

I Need your help. I *am* **dynamic** content , ***please*** help *me*.

is this word possible to print. Note the content is dynamic.
ZPL Code please.

Comment: I know it's old but if someone else has similar issue, have you already tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377181/make-text-in-zpl-label-bold-or-underlined

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type bold you can use this

^FO340,128^FDbold^FS
^FO339,128^FDbold^FS

Another option (External fonts usage for underline, italic and bold)
http://labelary.com/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to bold or italicize text withing ZPL. The fonts the printer has are very basic and can't be changed like that.

Comment: Is there anything now for doing it Italic?

Answer (score 0):

Complex font settings (italic, bold, serif ) are actually sent as compressed images to ZPL printers (you can check this with ZebraDesigner).
The format is called Z64, which is based on LZ77.
These two pages contain interesting code in Java to write a converter :

http://www.jcgonzalez.com/img-to-zpl-online

https://gist.github.com/trevarj/1255e5cbc08fb3f79c3f255e25989a18

...still I'm not sure whether the CRC part of the conversion will remain the same in the future, as this is probably vendor-dependent.

Here is a Python port of the first script :

```
import cv2
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import numpy

blacklimit=int(50* 768/100)
compress=False
total=0
width_byte=0
mapCode =  dict()
LOCAL_PATH="C://DEV//printer//zebra_debug.txt"
'''
class StringBuilder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._stringio = io.StringIO()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self._stringio.getvalue()
        
    def getvalue(self):
        return self._stringio.getvalue()
    
    def append(self, *objects, sep=' ', end=''):
        print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=self._stringio)
'''
def init_map_code():
    global mapCode
    mapCode[1] = "G"
    mapCode[2] = "H"
    mapCode[3] = "I"
    mapCode[4] = "J"
    mapCode[5] = "K"
    mapCode[6] = "L"
    mapCode[7] = "M"
    mapCode[8] = "N"
    mapCode[9] = "O"
    mapCode[10] = "P"
    mapCode[11] = "Q"
    mapCode[12] = "R"
    mapCode[13] = "S"
    mapCode[14] = "T"
    mapCode[15] = "U"
    mapCode[16] = "V"
    mapCode[17] = "W"
    mapCode[18] = "X"
    mapCode[19] = "Y"
    mapCode[20] = "g"
    mapCode[40] = "h"
    mapCode[60] = "i"
    mapCode[80] = "j"
    mapCode[100] = "k"
    mapCode[120] = "l"
    mapCode[140] = "m"
    mapCode[160] = "n"
    mapCode[180] = "o"
    mapCode[200] = "p"
    mapCode[220] = "q"
    mapCode[240] = "r"
    mapCode[260] = "s"
    mapCode[280] = "t"
    mapCode[300] = "u"
    mapCode[320] = "v"
    mapCode[340] = "w"
    mapCode[360] = "x"
    mapCode[380] = "y"
    mapCode[400] = "z"
        
def numberToBase(n, b):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        n //= b
    return digits[::-1]

def four_byte_binary(binary_str):
    
    decimal=int(binary_str, 2)
    if decimal>15:
        returned=hex(decimal).upper()
        returned=returned[2:]
    else:
        #returned=hex(decimal).upper()+"0"
        returned=hex(decimal).upper()
        if binary_str!="00000000":
            print("cut="+returned)
        returned=returned[2:]
        returned="0"+returned
        if binary_str!="00000000":
            print("low10="+returned)
    #
    if binary_str!="00000000":
        print(binary_str+"\t"+str(decimal)+"\t"+returned+"\t")
    return returned
    
def createBody(img):
    global blacklimit
    global width_byte
    global total
    height, width, colmap = img.shape 
    print(height)
    print(width)
    print(colmap)
    rgb = 0
    index=0
    aux_binary_char=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
    sb=[]
    if(width%8>0):
        width_byte=int((width/8)+1)
    else:
        width_byte=width/8
    total=width_byte*height
    print(height)
    print("\n")
    print(width)
    print("\n")
    i=0
    for h in range(0, height):
        for w in range(0, width):
            color = img[h,w]
            #print(color)
            #print(w)
            
            blue=color[0]
            green=color[1]
            red=color[2]
            blue=blue  & 0xFF
            green=green  & 0xFF
            red=red  & 0xFF
            """
            blue=np.uint8(blue)
            green=np.unit8(green)
            red=np.unit8(red)
            
            """
            #print(bin(blue))
            auxchar='1'
            total_color=red+green+blue
            if(total_color> blacklimit):
                #print('above_black_limit')
                auxchar='0'
            aux_binary_char[index]=auxchar
            index=index+1
            if(index==8 or w==(width-1)):
                if "".join(aux_binary_char) !="00000000":
                    print(i)
                sb.append(four_byte_binary("".join(aux_binary_char)))
                i=i+1
                aux_binary_char=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
                index=0
        #print(h)
        
        sb.append("\n")
    #print(sb)
    print(blacklimit)
    return ''.join(sb)

def encode_hex_ascii(code):
    global width_byte
    global mapCode
    max_linea=width_byte*2
    sb_code=[]
    sb_linea=[]
    previous_line=1
    counter=1
    aux = code[0]
    first_char=False
    for i in range(1, len(code)):
        if(first_char):
            aux=code[i]
            first_char=False
            continue
        if(code[i]=="\n"):
            if(counter>= max_linea and aux=='0'):
                sb_linea.append(",")
            elif(counter>= max_linea and aux=='F'):
                sb_linea.append("!")  
            elif(counter>20):
                multi20=int((counter/20))*20
                resto20=counter%20
                sb_linea.append(mapCode[multi20])  
                if(resto20!=0):
                    sb_linea.append(mapCode[resto20] +aux)  
                else:
                    sb_linea.append(aux)
            else:
                sb_linea.append(mapCode[counter] +aux)
            
            counter=1
            first_char=True
            if(''.join(sb_linea)==previous_line):
                sb_code.append(":")
            else:
                sb_code.append(''.join(sb_linea))
            previous_line=''.join(sb_linea)
            sb_linea=[]
            continue
        if aux==code[i]:
            counter=counter+1
        else:
            if counter>20:
                multi20=int((counter/20))*20
                resto20=counter%20
                sb_linea.append(mapCode[multi20]) 
                if resto20!=0:
                    sb_linea.append(mapCode[resto20] + aux)
                else:
                    sb_linea.append(aux)
            else:
                
                sb_linea.append(mapCode[counter] + aux)
            counter=1
            aux=code[i]
    return ''.join(sb_code)
    
def head_doc():
    global total
    global width_byte
    return "^XA " + "^FO0,0^GFA,"+ str(int(total)) + ","+ str(int(total)) + "," + str(int(width_byte)) +", "
    
def foot_doc():
    return  "^FS"+ "^XZ"    

def process(img):
    global compress
    init_map_code()
    cuerpo=createBody(img)
    print("CUERPO\n")
    print(cuerpo)
    print("\n")
    if compress:
        cuerpo=encode_hex_ascii(cuerpo)
        print("COMPRESS\n")
        print(cuerpo)
        print("\n")
    return head_doc() + cuerpo + foot_doc() 
    
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\ftheeten\\Pictures\\out.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
compress=True
blacklimit ==int(50* 768/100)
test=process(img)

file=open(LOCAL_PATH, 'w')
file.write(test)
file.close()
```