# How to print arial bold with a 12dpmm (300 dpi) printer?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

How can I print arial bold 12 dpmm(300dpi) printer?

I tried this but it is not working

```
^FT430,704^A0N,90,90 ^FH\^FD ARİAL Bold 12 ^FS
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377181/make-text-in-zpl-label-bold-or-underlined)

But I will give you a sample in this label [Here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=12&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFT30%2C604%5EA0N%2C90%2C90%20%5EFH%5C%5EFD%20AR%C4%B0AL%20Normal%2012%20%5EFS%20%20%0A%5EFT30%2C704%5EA0N%2C90%2C90%20%5EFH%5C%5EFD%20AR%C4%B0AL%20Bold%2012%20%5EFS%20%20%0A%5EFT32%2C702%5EA0N%2C90%2C90%20%5EFH%5C%5EFD%20AR%C4%B0AL%20Bold%2012%20%5EFS%20%20%0A%5EXZ)